# How to resolve duplicate key errors in pglogical after failover to DR node?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, database-replication, logical-replication, pglogical

We have set up logical replication using the pglogical extension and added the required tables to it. During the DR testing, we intentionally broke the replication and redirected the application to the DR node. However, we encountered issues with certain application functionalities due to duplicate errors on the primary key of certain tables. It should be noted that some tables have sequences associated with their primary keys, while others do not.

My question is, in pglogical, do we need to explicitly add the sequence to the replication set and synchronize it before performing the failover? Alternatively, should I reset the sequence every time I perform a failover? Please advise on the proper method to handle this primary key issue on the pglogical replication.